# Change layout on Android NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Is there a way to change the color of the two horizontal lines on the Android `NumberPicker`?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling your question?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will get you started:

http://devmobapps.blogspot.com/2011/09/numberpicker-use-and-customization-of.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

If you only care for changing the color of the NumberPicker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233556/changing-numberpicker-divider-color) is a very simple solution that uses the following.

```
private void setDividerColor(NumberPicker picker, int color) {

    java.lang.reflect.Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field pf : pickerFields) {
        if (pf.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {
            pf.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
                pf.set(picker, colorDrawable);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then call the function like this

```
setDividerColor(mNumberPicker, Color.GREEN);
```

## Solution 2

Although the first solution is simple it is limited. I'd recommend using [this](https://github.com/StephenVinouze/MaterialNumberPicker) repository which provides MaterialNumberPickers that allow for much greater customization. There are instructions on how to add Gradle dependencies in the ReadMe of the repo so I won't include them here but MaterialNumberPickers can then be added in xml as follows.

```
<com.github.stephenvinouze.materialnumberpickercore.MaterialNumberPicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:mnpMaxValue="50"
    app:mnpMinValue="1"
    app:mnpEditable="false"
    app:mnpFontname="Hand.ttf"
    app:mnpSeparatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:mnpTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:mnpTextSize="16sp"
    app:mnpTextStyle="bold"
    app:mnpValue="10"
    app:mnpWrapped="false" />
```

Additionally, MaterialNumberPicker extends NumberPicker so making this change in xml won't require any backend changes in your .java files.