# color of android numberpicker horizontal separator changes from API23 to API21

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am controlling the layout of my app on various devices with android device emulator, and passing (with the same device) from api23 to api21 the numberpicker separator that i use in a customdialog to select numbers in a screen preference changes from my color to a color which looks similar to the blue of the holo theme.

What can I do to fit my layout?

Comment: I tried to change style from my customdialog where I've already set "colorAccent" while in the main style of my app i set "colorControlNormal" "colorControlActivated" "android: textColorSecondary"....I'm using the AppCompat theme and the strange thing is that using the same device from one API to another is as if it no longer takes the settings

Comment: Even if I did not want to do it programmatically, I followed this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/29517329/7896028 ... and I modified it by removing the color passing by parameter and setting it within the function...however if you have a solution that implies changing a style's parameter/s i prefer