# Android: How to set max to min values of numberpicker with offset of 10

Tags: java, android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I want to have number picker with values 10,20,30,40,50
when I'm doing like this:

```
    minutePicker.setMaxValue(10);
    minutePicker.setMinValue(1);
    minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(values);
```

provided values is {"30", "40", "50", "60", "70"};

Im able to display values as expected but these are like edit text, when I'm taping on each value keyboard displays, how can I make it just display value as textview rather edit text

Comment: yes but its editable, how can i disable editable

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants", will Disable soft keyboard on numberpicker, this removes the ability to type in a value for the NumberPicker

Comment: where I can see properties that I can use on xml

Comment: also how can I remove divider line

Comment: you'll need to use reflection for the same. check this stackoverflow post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233556/changing-numberpicker-divider-color

Answer (score 0):

Create NumberPicker class like below

```
public class MyNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    processAttributeSet(attrs);
}

public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    processAttributeSet(attrs);
}
private void processAttributeSet(AttributeSet attrs) {
    //This method reads the parameters given in the xml file and sets the properties according to it
    this.setMinValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "min", 0));
    this.setMaxValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "max", 0));
}
```

}

Comment: could you elaborate, I want to remove divider line