# NumberPicker Material Style Custom Selection Divider

Tags: android, material-design, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I wanted to customize number picker selection divider.

[image: number picker selection divider]

I created custom drawable to be used for number picker selection divider.

I created custom material style inheriting number picker material style.

```
<style name="MyNumberPickerTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.NumberPicker">
    <item name="colorControlNormal ">#2e7d32</item>
    <item name="android:background">#69f0ae</item>
    <item name="selectionDivider">@drawable/my_number_picker_divider</item>
</style>
```

But selectionDivider property is not recognized. How can I add my custom drawable to number picker material style to set custom selection divider?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148671/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datepicker-divider/20291416#20291416.

Comment: That is not useful. Its not color of the selection divider that I want to change. I created a drawable to be used as selection divider of number picker. But can't assign it to number picker as selectionDivider property is not recognized getting compile error, even android:selectionDivider same issue.

Comment: you can set a drawable i haven't tried. but the posted link has a answer which uses reflection and a library is also suggested. take a look at the answer modify it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no easy way to accomplish this. [This StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29517329/2356570) is the only good enough solution in this case.
For the sake of other readers, I'll copy/paste the answer here.

```
private void setDividerColor(NumberPicker picker, Drawable customDrawable) {

    java.lang.reflect.Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field pf : pickerFields) {
        if (pf.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {
            pf.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                pf.set(picker, customDrawable);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And now somewhere in your code, you can call *setDividerColor(picker, drawableObject)* to set the color of the divider.

Comment: I am not trying to change the color of selection divider. I want to use custom drawable (different shape) as selection divider.

Comment: I've updated the answer to support drawable.

Comment: This is wrong, you shouldn't need to use reflection in order to fix this. Use a theme overlay to alter the value of `colorControlNormal` instead.